# Use of '' of which'' in sentence

Tags: relative-clauses

> I need the wheat flour **of which** I bought **20 kg.** two days ago.
>
> I need the wheat flour **20 kg. of which** I bought  two days ago.

Where should I use '' 20 kg.'' in the sentences above or would these sentences mean the same? I thought both have the same meaning but I couldn't be sure.

Comment: They're equivalent in meaning, but your first version is more "natural" (it doesn't require any special enunciation or punctuation, which the second version *does*). Note that simplest of all (and certainly preferred by ***me***) would be *I need the wheat flour **that** I bought 20 kg. **of** two days ago.*

Comment: You don't need a full stop after abbreviations of measures (kg, mm...).o

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica 20 kg of two days ago?

Comment: @user105719: Yes. But note that the words *20 kg of two days ago* do ***not*** constitute a "self-contained syntactic unit". It's just that's where we normally put the preposition. The alternative format is your second version *I need the wheat flour **of which I bought** 20 kg two days ago* (also valid, but my guess is idiomatically my version would be far more common in natural spoken contexts).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica why do you prefer "that" instead of "which" in the first comment? just asking out of curiosity

Comment: @Fermichem: It's not exactly a *strong* preference, but hopefully you can see that the syntax of ***that*** is inherently simpler. There's only one place you can put it, it needs no preposition, and you don't even *need* to include it at all. Even as a native speaker I usually prefer simplicity, and surely for you as a learner that should be the way to go.

Comment: Tell me, are you planning to use this in **conversation**? I need the wheat flour, which I bought 2 kg of two days ago". That is how we actually talk.

Comment: Isn't it,  'I need 20 kgs of wheat floor (from the lot) that I bought two days ago'?

Comment: The second seems to suggest “I have a vast supply of flour, *including* 20 kg that I bought two days ago.”

Comment: These aren't very natural, and using "of which" is very formal.   Perhaps reword it:  I need some of the wheat flour from the 20kg batch that I bought two days ago.

Comment: I agree "of which" is a bit formal however it's used, but "of which I bought 20 kg. two days ago" is even more formal than "20 kg. of which". I might expect to hear the latter used in speech occasionally, but not the former.

Answer (score 0):

They're both valid and mean the same thing, but I think you need a comma in at least one, and it would do no harm in both. As @FumbleFingers pointed out, neither is very natural in spoken English and arguably over-formal in written.

Most importantly, you are making a common English learners mistake of trying to work around 'of which' in a graceful way but ending up with something that sounds clunky. You are avoiding ending a clause with 'of' probably because you have been taught that to do so is 'wrong'. It really isn't. In fact, you can dispense with 'of which' entirely and form a shorter sentence which flows much better.

> I need the wheat flour I bought 20 kg **of** two days ago.
>
> I need the 20kg of wheat flour I bought two days ago.

'Which' and 'that' are both words that can often be omitted without any loss in meaning. When they can be, they usually should.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to disagree with the other answer and say that your usage is slightly off.

Here's why: you don't need the "the" before "wheat flour"

Either you need *some* wheat flour, and you happened to buy 20kg a few days ago, in which case you could say either:

> I need wheat flour, of which I bought 20 kg. two days ago.

or

> I need wheat flour, 20 kg. of which I bought two days ago.

The other situation is you need the exact amount you bought the other day (with most people inferring that you bought it for this specific purpose). In that case, you could say either:

> I need the wheat flour which I bought 20 kg. of two days ago.

or

> I need the 20 kg of wheat flour which I bought two days ago.

Comment: Completely unnatural sounding....sorry.

Comment: Whoa! Suppose that the speaker possesses several varieties of wheat flour and the one currently required is not the variety of which they recently bought 5 kg, but rather the one of which their acquisition amounted to 20 kg.